# Ionic 2 - how to make ion-button with icon and text on two lines?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

**THE SITUATION**:

In my Ionic 2 app I need to have the menu button on two lines: icon and text.

The problem is that somehow the ion-button directive force the button to be on one line.

I need the ion-button directive to be sure the button has always the proper formatting and positioning responsively.
I just need that button to be on two lines.

This the html and css of my attempt:

**THE HTML**:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="left" start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
      <br />
      <p class="menuSubTitle">MENU</p>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      HomePage
    </ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="right" end>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <br />
      <p lass="menuSubTitle">LOGIN</p>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**THE CSS**:

```css
.menuSubTitle {   
  font-size: 0.6em;
  float:left;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

**THE QUESTION**:

How can I make a ion-button on two lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are along the right lines. A slight modification is needed for it to work.

Here is my markup:

```
<button ion-button block color="menu-o">
    <div>
        <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
        <label>Flash</label>
    </div>
</button>
```

The inner `<div>` inside the `<button>` is the trick. The only thing needed for this markup is to set the `<label>` element to `display: block`.

Since `<p>` is already a block level element. It may just work as is.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
.button-inner {
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

This will change the element ordering from horizontal to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the button height if you want it a bit prettier. (e.g. with icon margin)

```
.button-icon-top {
  height: 5em;
  .button-inner {
    flex-flow: column;

    .icon {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }
}
```

Just add the class name to your button.

```html
<button ion-button full large class="button-icon-top">
  <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
  <span>Click me</span>
</button>
```